# Let $f(x)=p\cos x+q\sin x,|p|+|q|\ne0$ and $|f(x)|\leq 1$.Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the roots of the equation $f(x)=1,|\alpha-\beta|=k\pi,k\in R,$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $f(x)=p\cos x+q\sin x,|p|+|q|\ne0$ where $p,q\in R$ and $|f(x)|\leq 1$.Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the roots of the equation $f(x)=1,|\alpha-\beta|=k\pi,k\in R,$then the find the possible values of $k.$

---

$\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of the equation $f(x)=p\cos x+q\sin x=1$
$p\cos \alpha+q\sin \alpha=1......(1)$
$p\cos \beta+q\sin \beta=1......(2)$
But i am not able to solve further.Please help me.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{p^2+q^2}\sin(x+\arctan(pq^{-1}))\\
\implies 1=f(\alpha)\le\sqrt{p^2+q^2}=f({\pi\over2}-\arctan(pq^{-1})\le1\\
\implies f(x)=\sin(x+\arctan(pq^{-1}))$$

$f(x)$ is just a translated sine function. Therefore $\alpha$ is a solution to $f(x)=1$ iff so is $\alpha+2n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So the set we're looking for is $\mathbb{2N}\cup\{0\}$.